# How to send a GET request with Wget and output it on the screen

Tags: node.js, api, post, get, wget

The command below successfully sends GET requests to a secure server with the Wget Command which saves the output in the “*response_from_API_server.json*” file in the same directory.

Is there any way to show the command output on the screen instead of saving it into a file?

Sample code:

```
wget -S --ca-cert=/etc/ssl/AAA.crt 
--certificate=/etc/ssl/BBB.csp-DDD@EEE.cert.pem 
--private-key=/etc/ssl/BBB.csp-DDD@EEE.cert.key.pem 
--header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
--header='Accept-Charset: UTF-8'
--header='Content-Type: application/json' -O response_from_API_server.json
--post-data '{"email": "info@mail.com", "accountID": "myaccount1234"}' https: //examplewebsite.com//ourUsers/findAccount
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `-O response_from_API_server.json` try `-O-`. Instead of saving the response to a file it prints to stdout.

Comment: Awesome, I think that worked pretty well!


`Saving to: ‘STDOUT’
 [<=>                                                   ]       0  --.-KB/s              
 {"ourUsers":{""accountStatus":"ACTIVE","email":"info@mail.com"}                  
[ <=>                                                   ]     252  --.-KB/s    in 0s`


Thank you so much, @dwosk !

Comment: Glad it worked - would you mind marking this as the answer then? Thanks so much